# How to check if an image contains horizontal or vertical text region

Tags: image-processing

I have images with text written vertically in some cases and horizontally in others. I need to process horizontal and vertical text images differently. Hence, for that I need to first check if the image contains a vertical text or not.If someone can suggest some way of finding if an image contains vertical text or not, it will be helpful. For example see the following imageshttps://i.stack.imgur.com/A5txz.jpg  and https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LU28.jpg. The first one contains a vertical text and the second one contains a horizontal text.

Comment: option 1: you find any text and then check if it is vertical or horizontal
option 2: you use sliding horizontal and vertical windows so you can only recognize horizontal or vertical groups of characters (this of course requires some knowledge about text dimensions)

Comment: Fourier transform the image, analyse the amplitude spectrum, horizontal text will give you vertical spectrum, and vice-versa.